# Android phone keep broadcasting SSID

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, wifi-direct

I didn’t have android devices for years, I got a Xiaomi redmi 7 for my son but I don’t know why it keep broadcasting a SSID “Redmi”

From what I understand that the “WiFi Direct” (settings/Wi-Fi/Additional settings/WiFi direct)

I don’t see any option to turn it off, how can I prevent to broadcast any WiFi but allow to connect to an external WiFi network ?

I’m also surprise it’s won’t connect to 5Ghz, I assume it’s not compatible but that really funny for a smartphone bought in 2020

Comment: According to [GsmArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_7-9498.php) Xiaomi redmi 7 has only support for 2.4GHz Wifi: Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n. As usual you get what you pay for hence you can't expect much from a low budget phone (<150€). Regarding the `Redmi` wifi I would assume that the Hotspot feature is activated on the phone which allows to share the internet connection with other Wifi devices.

Comment: “ you can't expect much from a low budget phone (<150€).” agreed, regarding the hotspot feature yes that was my guess but I never found anything

Comment: Just to confirm, I checked again and portable hotspot is off already - saying that I realise that the phone is randomly broadcasting the "redmi" SSID, I guess it could be the user too (he claiming not doing anything but I don't understand how would that broadcast otherwise...)